# An error occurred while trying to change an Older Commit message

Tags: git

I used an *Interactive rebase tool* `git rebase -i HEAD~N` to retrieve older commits but it's throwing following error on the terminal.

> hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... brackets -n -w: brackets: command not found
>
> error: There was a problem with the editor 'brackets -n -w'.

Note: **I don't even have Brackets editor installed on my Mac. I uninstalled it long time back.**

Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Waiting+for+your+editor+to+close+the+file+command+not+found

Answer (score 0):

Configure your git to use the editor you want, for example:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Then run the rebase again.

Comment: What's the command for Visual Studio Code Editor? 
`git config --global core.editor vsc`   or 
`git config --global core.editor visual studio code`  

**I tried both but to no avail.**

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-editor

Comment: `code --help`  

`git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`  

`git config --global -e`